# xml file validation

Tags: xml, validation, jboss, weblogic

I am validaing a xml using following code snippet.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);
try
{
  Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
  Validator xmlValidator = schema.newValidator();
}
```

But I am receiving the following exception whne I am deploying in weblogic 11g server.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

When I am deploying same in jboss5.1 server. It giving no exception.

Can any one give nay suggestions please.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Weblogic has problems with the
>   XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI it
>   seems

as per the workaround given in [this forum thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2854537).